# Buscar por fecha en un campo que también contiene la hora

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto, programación-funcional

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos, necesito hacer la búsqueda por fecha, pero el campo también tiene hora.

```
const data = [
  {
    "direccion": "Calle 1 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "Suecia",
    "fecha": "25/04/2020 13:00:34"
  },
  {
    "direccion": "Calle 2 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "Panama",
    "fecha": "25/04/2020 18:00:55"
  },{
    "direccion": "Calle 3 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "Guatemala",
    "fecha": "01/04/2020 13:00:34"
  },{
    "direccion": "Calle 4 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "francia",
    "fecha": "01/04/2020 13:50:34"
  },{
    "direccion": "Calle 5 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "grecia",
    "fecha": "25/06/2020 10:00:34"
  },{
    "direccion": "Calle 6 Zona 4-55",
    "pais": "Peru",
    "fecha": "25/06/2020 11:00:34"
  },
]
```

Hasta ahora, solo he logrado realizar la busqueda por fecha y hora exacta con lo siguiente:

```
const getFecha = data.find(date => date.fecha === "25/04/2020 13:00:34")
```

Pero yo necesito poder hacer la busqueda solo por la fecha, por ejemplo, buscar todos los registros que pertenecen a la fecha "25-04-2020"

Comment: hola prueba a usar la condición `date.fecha.indexOf("aqui_tu_fecha") === 0;` en lugar de la comparación que usas con fecha y hora. Consulta [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: intenta con el metodo `contains()`

Comment: Si quieres obtener más de un elemento, entonces debes usar `.filter()`, porque con `.find()` solo te va a devolver la primera coincidencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar tu búsqueda

```
const getFecha = data.find(date => date.fecha === "25/04/2020 13:00:34")
```

Por

```
let getFecha = data.filter(x => x.fecha.includes("25/06/2020"));
```

Esto te devuelve todos los elementos en donde la fecha coincide con lo escrito en la función includes y aparte al declararlo como una variable puedes modificar su contenido cuando lo necesites.

Comment: Funciono!!! Gracias